# how to override adminhtml block for a function?

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, override-block

Urapidflow has an issue which casued by a security patch and even their new version does not resolve the issue,
the path for module file that I want to write an override is:

```
app\code\community\Unirgy\RapidFlow\Block\Adminhtml\Profile\Edit\Tab\Upload.php
```

anyways I have to rewrite the following:

```
  $this->getUploader()->getConfig()
```

this should be

```
 $this->getUploader()->getUploaderConfig()
```

to work fine. here is the module path:
Unirgy_RapidFlow_Block_Adminhtml_Profile_Edit_Tab_Upload

I am creating a module to rewrite the functions inside it, here is what I did:

app\code\local\Scosche\Unirgy\etc\config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Scosche_Unirgy>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Scosche_Unirgy>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <scosche_unirgy>
                <class>Scosche_Unirgy_Block</class>
            </scosche_unirgy>
             <unirgy_rapidFlow>
                <rewrite>
                    <adminhtml_profile_edit_tab_upload>Scosche_Unirgy_Block_Adminhtml_Profile_Edit_Tab_Upload</adminhtml_profile_edit_tab_upload>
                </rewrite>
             </unirgy_rapidFlow>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

This is wrong for some reason I created the same folders and path on scosche module but although I can see module is active in Advanced configuration, it is not working,
app\code\community\Unirgy\RapidFlow\etc\config.xml:

```
<blocks>
    <urapidflow><class>Unirgy_RapidFlow_Block</class></urapidflow>
</blocks>
```

please let me know what's wrong.[image]

Comment: Are you sure that `unirgy_rapidFlow` is the correct block alias? Meaning, is this the one that can be found under `app/code/*SCOPE*/Unirgy/RapidFlow/etc/config.xml` inside the `<blocks>` node?

Comment: it is app\code\community\Unirgy\RapidFlow\Block\Adminhtml\Profile\Edit\Tab\Upload.php

Comment: That doesn't say anything about the alias used for `Unirgy_RapidFlow_Block` - this you need to check in the config.xml of the module first.

Comment: Show us `***Unirgy/RapidFlow/etc/config.xml` file please.

Comment: @ChristophFarnleitner I updated the question, sorry I got your mean now, alias is urapidflow

Comment: @ChristophFarnleitner OMG!!! you guys fixed my problem, I changed the unirgy_rapidFlow to urapidflow now it is working, Christopher please post an answer so I can check mark it

Comment: You're welcome, @Nickool. I hope below answer is a sufficient explanation on what we discussed aboove :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, one common mistake is the assumption that for example a model or block rewrite is to be done based on `Vendor_Modulename`.

This means, to create a proper rewrite for a core and/or a third party module the one must take a look at the modules `etc/config.xml` and find the actual alias/identifier that is defined for the model or block in question.

A basic example:

In case you want to rewrite a certain method of `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product.php` you'll first have to check in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml` to find something like this:

```
<config>
    [...]
    <global>
        [...]
        <blocks>
            <catalog> <!-- this is our node of interest -->
                <class>Mage_Catalog_Block</class>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
        [...]
    </global>
    [...]
</config>
```

This tells us, that our rewrites must be based on `catalog` (rather than `mage_catalog` or anything else). This then will allow us to rewrite a block class in our custom module by setting up something like the following:

```
<config>
    [...]
    <global>
        [...]
        <blocks>
             <catalog> <!-- based on what we found in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml/ -->
                <rewrite>
                    <product>Vendor_Module_Block_Product</product>
                </rewrite>
             </catalog>
        </blocks>
        [...]
    </global>
    [...]
</config>
```